# Simple&efficient slider module for the following purpose

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm looking for a recommendation of a rather simple, conventional, D7 carousel\rotator\slider module that will let just to replace images (without many advanced techniques).

What I do need this module to have, and doesn't very much compromise about, is these features:

1. Pointers (Left and right) to move between pics.
2. Small dots that reflect the current picture being shown.
3. Text that "comes" into the center of the picture from different
   directions, and that Ican have full management of it's appearance
   (Font-Family, size, color, etc).

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: have you bothered to actually do any research?  have you tried any of the dozen or so sliders out there?

Answer (score 0):

[Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) isn't a bad way to go. It will probably take some working with css/templates/views to get it to display the way you want, but it is the most used module, so if you find yourself up against a wall using it, there's a good chance someone's already has done it and has written a tutorial, or would answer a question.

There are a few other modules out there you could look at. A quick search I found this page, which has a [decent list](http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/5-best-drupal-slideshows)

Also a very in-depth comparison on the different modules out there from [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/418616)